# Docpad : show error/success message on contact form

Tags: express, docpad

I added a route in my `docpad.coffee` file to handle form submissions, that I validate using the [express-validator middleware](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator). Now depending on the validation, I want to redirect the users to the same contact page but displaying either a success message when validation is successful (here I'll send an email), or display the error messages.

I didn't manage to pass the validation message to the template to display it. I tried almost all combinations of `dynamic: true/false`, `res.locals = validationMessages`, `res.sessions = validationMessages`, `res.templateData = validationMessages` with no success.

Furthermore, adding `dynamic: true` made the changes to the content not appear at all, whatever refresh strategy I use (private mode, cleaning cache, relaunching Docpad, refreshing without cache, etc.). I should probable file a bug about it.

How to ?

I'm using Docpad 6.53.0 (latest to date), node 0.10.15, on OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 2):

I cheated on this one a bit by appending a hash to the redirect url (eg: "www.mywebsite.com/#messagesent"). I then use client side javascript to read the hash and then show the appropriate message. Something like this:

```
if (location.hash == "#messagesent") {  
    $('#message-sent').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#message-sent').fadeOut(1000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Not quite what you were asking though :)

Comment: A workaround, but doesn't work with JavaScript deactivated. I'll try anyway if I don't manage to do it server-side.

Comment: I think you should be able to do the same thing on the server side - ie look at the hash of the url/request.